# local keyword does not work with references

Tags: perl

The following code prints `<oof foo zab><foo foo baz>`:

```
use v5.36;
use warnings;

our $foo = 'foo';
our %bar = (
  foo => \$foo,
  baz => 'baz',
);

{
  local ($foo, %bar) = ($foo, %bar);
  ($foo, $bar{baz}) = qw(oof zab);
  print "<$foo ${$bar{foo}} $bar{baz}>";
}

print "<$foo ${$bar{foo}} $bar{baz}>";
```

Is there a way to make it print `<oof oof zab><foo foo baz>` without copy/pasting `%bar`s definition into the inner scope?

EDIT:

I realize that I have phrased my question poorly.

The outer scope represents some given code with many such `$foo`s and `%bar`s as well as functions which behave according to those variables.

The inner scope represents tests for the outer scope, where I wanted to localize variables, modify them and test how the functions behave. Each test was supposed to start with the initial conditions, thus the `local`. It is not feasible to duplicate the many variable assignments into the inner scope, because that might become outdated quickly.

My question might look like an xy-problem, but I had hoped that `local`s current behaviour is a perl bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
use Sub::ScopeFinalizer qw( scope_finalizer );

{
   my $old_foo = $foo;
   my $guard = scope_finalizer { $foo = $old_foo };

   $foo = "oof";

   say $bar{ foo }->$*;  # oof
}

say $bar{ foo }->$*;  # foo
```

---

Since you're using 5.36, you could forgo the module in lieu of an experimental feature added that version.

```perl
use experimental qw( defer );

{
   my $old_foo = $foo;
   defer { $foo = $old_foo };

   $foo = "oof";

   say $bar{ foo }->$*;  # oof
}

say $bar{ foo }->$*;  # foo
```

Comment: It is essentially a reimplementation of `local` which I hoped to avoid. I'll accept your answer unless someone comes up with a magic flag for `local` or something.

Comment: `local` doesn't have flags. If you can't use `local`, you have to use something `local`-like

Answer (score 2):

Without using any extra modules:

```
use v5.36;
use warnings;

our $foo = 'foo';
our %bar = (
  foo => \$foo,
  baz => 'baz',
);

{
  local $foo = 'oof';
  local $bar{foo} = \$foo;
  print "<$foo ${$bar{foo}} $bar{baz}>";
}

print "<$foo ${$bar{foo}} $bar{baz}>";
```

prints `﻿﻿﻿<oof oof baz><foo foo baz>`.

You can localize a single hash entry even if the hash is lexical (i.e. created as `my %bar`), but you can not localize a lexical scalar. The `local` built-in replaces the variable itself, not just its value, so `$bar{foo}` continues to refer to the original `$foo`.

Comment: `local $bar{foo} = \$foo` means that I need to know about the contents of the outer scope variables.

Comment: Correct. That is the way `local` works. If this is unacceptable for your use case, you may have to go with something like [Scope::Guard](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scope::Guard) to ensure that values get restored after you tweak them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function which returns hash pairs,

```
use warnings;

our $foo = 'foo';

sub pairs {
  foo => \$foo,
  baz => 'baz',
};
our %bar = pairs();

{
  # local ($foo, %bar) = ($foo, pairs());
  local $foo = $foo;
  local %bar = pairs();
  ($foo, $bar{baz}) = qw(oof zab);
  print "<$foo ${$bar{foo}} $bar{baz}>";
}

print "<$foo ${$bar{foo}} $bar{baz}>";
```

Output

```
<oof oof zab><foo foo baz>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't actually **do** this in real code as [symbolic references](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Symbolic-references) are generally and rightfully considered a Bad Idea, but using one makes it work in this case:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
no strict 'refs'; # Danger, Will Robinson!
use feature qw/say/;

our $foo = 'foo';
our %bar = (
    foo => 'foo', # This is the *name* of the package variable to reference
    baz => 'baz'
);

{
    local ($foo, $bar{baz}) = qw/oof zab/;
    say "<$foo ${$bar{foo}} $bar{baz}>"; # <oof oof zab>
}

say "<$foo ${$bar{foo}} $bar{baz}>"; # <foo foo baz>
```

Comment: You changed the outer scope variable contents. I cannot do that.